# Should I use with or of for these example sentences?

Tags: prepositions

> As a Customer Service Manager, I managed a department **with**/**of** 10 advisors.

> I worked in a residence hall **with**/**of** 500 first-year students.

How do I know which one to use?

Answer (score 0):

**Of** is more likely to describe the entirety of the group, while **with** often describes a subset.

So a department **of** 10 advisors is probably a department **with** 10 advisors and nobody else.

A department **with** 10 advisors may have other kinds of members who are not advisors.